# Swift - Update auto layout properties of UI components programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

To design and create my UI, I always use auto layouts and do it programmatically instead of using storyboard.
In every `view` class of mine, I have a method called

```
private func setupView(frame:CGRect) {
      /* START CONTAINER VIEW */
    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(containerView)
    
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: frame.width * (13 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -frame.width * (13 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: frame.height * (26 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    /* END CONTAINER VIEW */
    ...
}
```

to initialize the components. Now let's say, in the method above, I initialize 10 UI components which are properly displayed when I run my code. However, depending on some variables, I have another function that is being called

```
private func addNextRoundInformation() {
   ..
    nextRoundLabel = UILabel()
    nextRoundLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(nextRoundLabel)
    
    nextRoundLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentRoundLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:currentRoundLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundEndsInLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
}
```

which should place a new label between some others which were already initialized.
Of course, when putting the new label between some particular ones, I also update the auto layout constraints of the of the bottom label like

```
 private func updateNumberOfWinnersLabelConstraint() {
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nextRoundLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nextRoundLabelValue.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
}
```

The **topAnchor** of each label depends on the bottom anchor of the previous one.

With this approach, I can't see **nextRoundLabel** at all. It only appears, if I initialize it in the **private func setupView(frame:CGRect) {}**

Why?

Comment: Do you see any log issues for constraints ? if so copy them here, or share a github demo of the problem

Comment: "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283267890 V:[UILabel:0x10ed14ef0]-(21.0079)-[UILabel:0x10ed15630]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2832291d0 V:[UILabel:0x10ed14ef0]-(21.0079)-[UILabel:0x10ed22cb0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2832293b0 V:[UILabel:0x10ed22cb0]-(21.0079)-[UILabel:0x10ed15630]   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2832291d0 V:[UILabel:0x10ed14ef0]-(21.0079)-[UILabel:0x10ed22cb0]   (active)>

I do get some logs!

Comment: @Melodias - you need to provide some more information. You have a (vertical) set of UI components, with each having its Top constrained to the previous view's Bottom, and you're trying to "insert" a view between two of them? As in `viewA -> viewB` to `viewA -> viewX -> viewB`? If so, you need to remove the *existing* `A->B` constraints. As a side note, this sounds like a perfect scenario for using a `UIStackView` instead of all of those constraints...

Comment: Hello @DonMag, yes exactly! I am trying to insert viewX between viewA and viewB. Alright, I'll try the approach with removing existing contraints. Which ones do I have to remove? From viewB only?

Comment: @DonMag, @Sh_Khan

I guess, when I call the method `private func addNextRoundInformation()` from another view controller, the constraints of the UI components are not accessible to me? Because within that method, if I print

 `print(currentRoundLabel.constraints)`
 `print(roundEndsInLabel.constraints)`

I get "[]". This would explain why my `nextRoundLabel` is not visible at all

Comment: @Melodias - it's not that the constraints are "not accessible" ... you are getting auto-layout error messages, which indicate that the constraints you are trying to set are conflicting with each other. See my answer for how to do this with a `UIStackView` -- it sounds like a much easier approach.

Comment: Hello @DonMag, I found actually a solution by keeping the way with only updating the topConstraints of the `numberOfWinnersLabel`

Answer (score 0):

You ***could*** do this with "Top-to-Bottom" constraints, but it would be rather complex.

You would need to essentially create a "Linked List" to track each view, the views above and below it, and its constraints.

So, to "insert" a new view after the 3rd view, you would need to:

- deactivate the inter-view constraints
- insert the new view into the linked list
- re-create and activate the new constraints

Putting your views in a `UIStackView` turns that process into a single line of code:

```
stackView.insertArrangedSubview(newView, at: 3)
```

Here's a quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testView: SampleView = SampleView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let infoLabel: UILabel = {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.numberOfLines = 0
            v.text = "Tap to Insert \"New Label\"\nafter \"Label 3\""
            return v
        }()
        let btn: UIButton = {
            let v = UIButton()
            v.setTitle("Insert", for: [])
            v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            return v
        }()
        
        [infoLabel, btn, testView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            infoLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            infoLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
        ])
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        testView.insertNew()
    }
    
}

class SampleView: UIView {
    
    var containerView: UIView!
    var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = .red
        setupView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    private func setupView(frame:CGRect) {
        /* START CONTAINER VIEW */
        containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(containerView)
        
        stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 12),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

        ])
        
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        /* END CONTAINER VIEW */
        
        // add 10 labels to the stack view
        for i in 1...10 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = .green
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

    }
    
    func insertNew() {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "New Label"
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // we're adding a label after 3rd label
        stackView.insertArrangedSubview(v, at: 3)
    }
}
```

It starts looking like this:

[image]

after tapping the "Insert" button, it looks like this:

[image]

---

**Edit**

To explain why your current approach isn't working...

Starting with this layout:

[image]

each label's **Top** is constrained to the previous label's **Bottom** (with `constant: spacing`).

Those constraints are indicated by the blue arrows.

You then want to "insert" `Next Round Label` between `Round Ends In` and `Winners Per Round`:

[image]

Your code:

- adds the label
- adds a constraint from the **Top** of `Next Round Label` to the **Bottom** of `Round Ends In`
- adds a constraint from the **Top** of `Winners Per Round` to the **Bottom** of `Next Round Label`

***but...*** `Winners Per Round` already has a `.topAnchor` connected to `Round Ends In`, so it now has **two** top anchors.

The conflicting constraints are shown in red:

[image]

As I said, I think your description of what you're trying to do would lend itself to using stack views, and would make "inserting" views so much easier.

But, if you need to stick with your current "Top-to-Bottom" constraints approach, you have several options.

One - remove all the labels, then re-add and re-constrain them, including the one you're inserting.

Two - track the constraints (using an array or custom object properties) so you can deactivate the conflicting constraint(s).

Three - use some code along the lines of

```
let theConstraint = containerView.constraints.first(where: {($0.secondItem as? UILabel) == roundEndsInLabel})
```

to "find" the constraint that needs to be deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

First, I declared two helper variables

```
/* START HELPER VARIABLES */
var numberOfWinnersLabelTopConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
var numberOfWinnersLabelValueTopConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
/* END HELPER VARIABLES */
```

then I made some minor adjustments in my **setupView** function:

```
private func setupView(frame:CGRect) {
   ...
     /* START NUMBER OF WINNERS PER ROUND LABEL */
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel = UILabel()
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel)
    
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentRoundLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:currentRoundLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
   // numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundEndsInLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true  // Replacing with helper variable
    
    numberOfWinnersLabelTopConstraint = numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundEndsInLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    numberOfWinnersLabelTopConstraint?.isActive = true
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(NUMBER_OF_WINNERS_PER_ROUND_TEXT, comment: "")
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.textColor = .darkGray
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    /* END NUMBER OF WINNERS PER ROUND LABEL */

    /* START NUMBER OF WINNERS PER ROUND LABEL VALUE */
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue = UILabel()
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue)
    
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentRoundLabelValue.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:currentRoundLabelValue.widthAnchor).isActive = true
  //  numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true // replacing with helper variable
    
    numberOfWinnersLabelValueTopConstraint = numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.topAnchor)
    numberOfWinnersLabelValueTopConstraint?.isActive = true
    
    numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.textColor = .black
    /* END NUMBER OF WINNERS PER ROUND LABEL VALUE */
```

By introducing the helper variables, I could easily deactivate the **topConstraint** when adding the **nextRoundLabel**

```
 private func addNextRoundInformation() {
    nextRoundLabel = UILabel()
    nextRoundLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(nextRoundLabel)

    nextRoundLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentRoundLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:currentRoundLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
  
    nextRoundLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundEndsInLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabel.text = "Next round starts in"
    nextRoundLabel.textColor = .darkGray
    nextRoundLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    nextRoundLabelValue = UILabel()
    nextRoundLabelValue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(nextRoundLabelValue)
    
    nextRoundLabelValue.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentRoundLabelValue.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabelValue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:currentRoundLabelValue.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabelValue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:nextRoundLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nextRoundLabelValue.textColor = .black
    nextRoundLabelValue.text = "Next round label value"
    nextRoundLabelValue.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
}

private func updateNumberOfWinnersLabelConstraint() {
    numberOfWinnersLabelTopConstraint?.isActive = false // Deactivate previous constraint
    numberOfWinnersLabelValueTopConstraint?.isActive = false
    
    numberOfWinnersLabelTopConstraint =  numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nextRoundLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    numberOfWinnersLabelTopConstraint?.isActive = true
    
    numberOfWinnersLabelValueTopConstraint = numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nextRoundLabelValue.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    numberOfWinnersLabelValueTopConstraint?.isActive = true
}
```

Basically, I only had to update the *topConstraints* of the **numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabel** and **numberOfWinnersPerRoundLabelValue**
since everything else would be the same. No changes needed for *currentRoundLabel*.

I tested it and it worked!